# Delete secret after lease time

Tags: hashicorp-vault, spring-vault

I'm starting to use the vault and when I add a secret in the vault I'm passing the lease = 10s but after 10s the secret is not being removed. How can I get the secret removed from the vault?

```
vault write -address=http://localhost:8200 secret/foo name=foo lease=10s
Success! Data written to: secret/foo

vault read -address=http://localhost:8200 -format=json secret/foo
{
        "request_id": "498db605-a238-2d99-2e36-7045c826f48d",
        "lease_id": "",
        "lease_duration": 10,
        "renewable": false,
        "data": {
                "lease": "10s",
                "name": "foo"
        },
        "warnings": null
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TTL for secrets on the KV secret backend it wasn't actually for deleting the secret, it was more of an advisory field to whatever was retrieving the secret: https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/kv/index.html#ttls

> Unlike other secrets engines, the KV secrets engine does not enforce TTLs for expiration. Instead, the lease_duration is a hint for how often consumers should check back for a new value. This is commonly displayed as refresh_interval instead of lease_duration to clarify this in output.
>
> Even will a ttl set, the secrets engine never removes data on its own. The ttl key is merely advisory.

You might be able to use cubbyhole's to enforce the TTL on some kind of secret as as soon as the token expires the cubbyhole will be destroyed. Each cubbyhole is scoped only to the token that is using it and no 2 tokens can access each others cubbyhole however: https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/cubbyhole/index.html